# Funny teleporter invention story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, teleportation, humor

I remember this short story as very funny. It was told in retrospect in the first person by a member of a fairly slap-happy team of inventors developing a new teleportation device.

Initially, there are some amusing experiments with rabbits, I think. And I distinctly remember that they were sued by an irate female film star or celeb because she arrived with her nose in the wrong place. There were also further disasters and law suits.

I think I read this c.1978-79 in a cheap anthology.

Comment: Did it perchance involve the rabbits showing up without bones?

Comment: If so, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149927/science-fiction-short-story-where-matter-transmission-cant-transmit-the-skeleto would match, but no starlet with a misplaced nose

Answer (score 32, accepted):

["Travel by Wire!"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel_by_Wire!) is a science fiction short story by English writer Arthur C. Clarke.

> Fortunately these difficulties have been largely overcome now that we
> use the micro-beams for our carrier, though now and then accidents
> still occur.  I expect you remember that big lawsuit we had last year
> with Lita Cordova, the television star, who claimed £1,000,000 damages
> from us for alleged loss of beauty.  She asserted that one of her eyes
> had moved during a transmission, but I couldn't see any difference
> myself and nor could the jury, who had enough opportunity.

Its an eye and not a nose, and a guinea pig and not a rabbit. And it is quite funny story.

Comment: The story can be read at https://archive.org/details/collectedstories00clar/page/n13/mode/2up (may require a free check-out).

Comment: Yes, that's definitely it. I mixed up the details but now I recognise. I remember laughing out loud at this in the library and getting disapproving looks. Thanks.

Comment: Clarke's first story, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen First *published* story at least.  There's probably some older un-published stuff floating around...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots. What have you done!? I ended up slogging through all 966 pages. Pretty good stuff for the most part. I even ended up asking this question: https://history.stackexchange.com/q/69054/37445 about one of the blurbs at the end.